# ggplot boxplot: same colour looks different depending when it is set

Tags: r, ggplot2

Just encountered a surprising colour problem while doing a boxplot with ggplot2.

The same colour (`#FF4040`) looks drastically different whether I set it as `fill` parameter or later in `scale_fill_manual`.

Here is an example you can copy/paste using the `mtcars` dataset.

```
library(ggplot2)
data('mtcars')

ggplot (data = mtcars, aes(x = as.factor(cyl), disp)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = '#FF4040'))

ggplot (data = mtcars, aes(x = as.factor(cyl), disp)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = as.factor(cyl)))+
  scale_fill_manual(breaks=c('4', '6', '8'),
                    values=c('#FF4040', '#FF4040', '#FF4040'))
```

Here is the comparison:

[image]

Comment: Intresting, when you change in first example `geom_boxplot(aes(fill= '#FF4040'))` to `geom_boxplot(fill= '#FF4040')` it is the same as the second one.

Comment: Ah, good call! I am simply not changing the colour at all in the first example. ggplot is using the default one. It is just an unlucky coincidence that it looks similar to the one I wanted to use so I thought I was controlling it. Happy to accept it if one of you wants to write the explanation as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comments in first example you don't change fill color only mapping fill. So instead of `geom_boxplot(aes(fill= '#FF4040'))` put `geom_boxplot(fill= '#FF4040')` and you recive the same result as the second version.